# What are the different types of Models in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

Loopback framework allows you to create several types of Models. The list looks something like:

> 1. Model
> 2. PersistedModel
> 3. ACL
> 4. AccessToken
> 5. Application
>      ...

What are these various types and when to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#built-in-models)'s a link to the base-models

Most of our models inherit from Persisted Model.  When you have an embedsMany relation, they suggest to use "Model" as your base model.

We also use User as our base model for our own website's users, only because the base model didn't have enough properties.

if you do a search for "Loopback" in GitHub, you will see a number of example repositories showing how loopback is used.